# MySQL table data physical fragmentation

Tags: mysql, optimization, fragmentation

Could you tell me, will MySQL data in tables be physically fragmented if I insert new data and delete old data (insert in table top, and delete bottom rows)?

Will the size of table be growing in any way, before I do OPTIMIZE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you `DELETEing` and `INSERTing` at about the same rate?  Is the table InnoDB?

If Yes to both, then "don't worry".  The `DELETEs` will free up blocks and the `INSERTs` will re-use those blocks (or new blocks if the `INSERTs` are getting ahead).

InnoDB tables are composed of 16KB blocks that are chained together in a BTree structure.  What you described will be freeing blocks from one side of the tree and creating new blocks on the other side.  However, each block can reside anywhere, so the concept of "side of the tree" is more 'virtual' than 'physical'.

After you have done a lot of churning, try the `OPTIMIZE` *once*.  If it does not cut the table size in half, that is a further clue that `OPTIMIZE` is not worth it.  A 30% shrinkage after a lot of churn is somewhat typical.  But it stabilizes at about that, and won't go over about 30%.

If, on the other hand, you are `DELETEing` *most* of the table all at once, then you may be better off rebuilding the table with the not-to-be-deleted rows.  This combines the delete and the optimize steps into one.  Then use this to flip the tables 'instantly':

```
RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;  DROP TABLE old;
```

And do *not* do any inserts during the rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

When innodb_file_per_table is OFF and all data is going to be stored in ibdata files. When you remove rows, they are just marked as deleted on disk but space will be consumed by InnoDB files which can be re-used later when you insert/update more rows but it will never shrink.
            If you drop some tables of delete some data then there is no any other way to reclaim that unused disk space except dump/reload method.

But, if you are using innodb_file_per_table then you can reclaim the space by running OPTIMIZE TABLE on that table. OPTIMIZE TABLE will create a new identical empty table. Then it will copy row by row data from old table to the new one. In this process a new .ibd tablespace will be created and the space will be reclaimed However, the shared tablespace-ibdata1 can still grow.

For more info-  [mysql reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/optimize-table.html) and [percona expert](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/09/25/how-to-reclaim-space-in-innodb-when-innodb_file_per_table-is-on/)